# Imported Sqlite Database not working in Android

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been struggling with database import to my android project for a while, I'm new to android. 
I know that android supports sqlite so my first question is do I have to remove the .sqlite extension and replace it with .db since in the examples that I found on the net  I only saw the .db extension files?. After I do that I place my existing database file to my assets folder and use a class to manage(create,copy) my database.

This is the tutorial which I am folowing:

http://www.reigndesign.com/blog/using-your-own-sqlite-database-in-android-applications/

In the tutorial it says that I must rename all of my id columns to _id , is that mandatory?

Comment: Yes, that is mandatory.

Comment: The extension can be **anything** (better if **.db**). The `_id` field is **not** mandatory. I have **all** of my DBs **without** an `_id` field. I call it whatever I want.  If I need a special method that requires an `_id` field I fake it using the `rowID AS _id` trick. `rowID` is a special "hidden" field that behaves exactly as if it was the `_id` field

Comment: Tnx for the reply. I forgot to ask, is there a problem if one or two tables do not have a primary key defined?

Comment: @Frank - you should post that as an answer; I see DB questions all the time, and those are good points. Let us vote for you!

Comment: One more thing that you could post in your answer is to give the answer to this: Open your database and add a new table called "android_metadata", you can execute the following SQL statement to do it:

CREATE TABLE "android_metadata" ("locale" TEXT DEFAULT 'en_US')
Now insert a single row with the text 'en_US' in the "android_metadata" table:

INSERT INTO "android_metadata" VALUES ('en_US'),,, is this mandatory as well or can I avoid it when creating the database in a sqlite editor?

Comment: It's automatically created in a new SQLite db.

Comment: You saved me so much time with this 3 little answers!!

Comment: I'm happy for that. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The extension can be **anything** (better if .db).
The _id field is **not** mandatory.
I have **all** (really) of my DBs without an _id field.

I call the id fields whatever I want.
If then I need a `special method` that requires an `_id` field, then I **fake it** using the `rowID AS _id` trick.
`rowID` is a special "hidden" field that behaves exactly as if it was the `_id` field.